# Конструктор перемещения/оператор перемещающего присваивания

Tags: c++, c++11, конструктор, оператор-присваивания

Используются реализации оператора копирования и конструктора копирования (не перемещающие) с закрытой функцией-методом `swap()` в `operator=()`, соответственно, в операторе также вызывается конструктор копирования для создания временного объекта.

Сейчас добавляю в класс перемещающие оператор присваивания и конструктор. Например:

```
MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&& other)
{
    *this = std::move(other); // через оператор?
}

MyClass& MyClass::operator=(MyClass&& rhs)
{
    rhs.swap(*this); // или this->swap(rhs);
    Solution().swap(rhs); // это ок

    return *this;
}
```

Вот мне интересно, является ли эта реализация оптимальной, в частности, здесь уже к-р использует оператор, это не плохо? Можно сделать списки инициализации в к-ре, например:

```
MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&& other) :
    value_1(std::move(other.value_1)),
    value_2(std::move(other.value_2))
{}
```

Даст ли это какое-то преимущество? Напишите, пожалуйста, каков оптимальный вариант, на Ваш взгляд, реализации этих двух спец. функций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&& other)
{
    *this = std::move(other);
}
```

Что будете делать в таком коде, если членами класса являются ссылки, константы и объекты классов, не имеющих default конструктора? А ничего, оно просто не соберется.

> Даст ли это какое-то преимущество?

В случае с присваиванием, объекты уже созданы, поэтому конкретные преимущества зависят от членов класса. Если у членов класса тяжелая инициализация, то к моменту `*this = std::move(other);` они уже должны быть созданы (если это вообще возможно), а значит мы потратили кучу ресурсов на совершенно не нужные телодвижения.

> Напишите, пожалуйста, каков оптимальный вариант, на Ваш взгляд, реализации этих двух спец. функций.

Для начала, обеим не мешает добавить `noexcept`.
Ну и swap - это всё-таки обмен, т.е. текущий объект просто переместится и не будет уничтожен. Это то поведение, которое Вы ожидаете во внешнем коде?
С другой стороны, так ли нужно уничтожать этот объект?
Здесь, скорее всё зависит от Вас. Я бы ожидал, что объект, который я замещаю всё-таки сразу улетучится.